# If $x = 100 + “25%” + “$40” what is the value of $x in php and why?

Tags: php

I have faced a question in an interview,

> If $x = 100 + “25%” + “$40” what is the value of $x  in php and why?

And i confused with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try it out? 

Comment: `$x` is as worthless as the code, and should result in at least 4 hours in the office pillory.

Comment: What is confusing to you in the question?

Comment: Did you pass your interview?...

Comment: Are the fancy quotes in your question deliberate?  If so: a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x=125 because:

Addition of integer and strings, php then tries to convert string to number. This is by taking the number at the begin until a char which is not part of a valid number.

"25%"= 25

"$40"= 0

$x=100+25+0=125

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, `$x` will be equal to an integer `125`, and will also throw a notice and a warning in PHP 7.1 and higher.

```
php > echo 100 + '25%' + '$40';
PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in php shell code on line 1
PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in php shell code on line 1
125
```

This is because PHP's [addition](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator only calculates numeric types, and tries to implicitely cast all parameters to either an `integer` or a `float`. Interestingly, trying to this with an `array` will cause PHP to simply crash because of an unsupported operand type.

```
php > echo 10 + [20];
PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in php shell code on line 1
```

---

For the sake of completion, I also tried it in some other languages.

**Python 3**

```
print(100 + '25%' + '$40')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

**Javascript**

```
console.log(100 + '25%' + '$40');
10025%$40
```

**Java**

```
System.out.println(100 + "25%" + "$40");
10025%$40
```

**C#**

```
Console.Write(100 + "25%" + "$40");
10025%$40
```